# Очищение всех сообщений не являющихся картинками или ссылками при помощи discord.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord-api

У меня есть бот в дискорде на JavaScript и мне нужно запускать таймер в 24 часа и очищать все сообщения в определённом канале если это они не являются картинками или не ссылками, так как я не знаю как тут работают таймеры и как отличать сообщения с текстом от сообщений с картинками, прошу помочь(просьба писать не готовый скрипт, а хотя бы объяснить принцип работы всего этого )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для того чтобы работать с сообщениями, надо их захватить (зафетчить), при этом сам API позволяет захватывать только 100 последних сообщений в канале. Поэтому все сообщения в определенном канале, вероятно, очистить не получится.
2. Для того чтобы понять есть ли вложение в виде картинки нужно зайти в структуру сообщения (message.attachments)
3. Ссылки Discord.js определять не умеет, проще всего будет написать для этого регулярку и проверять message.content
4. Таймеры работают как и в обычном Node. Так что тут либо делать setTimeout или setInterval, либо использовать cron.